# Confusion about predicted value from two-tree xgboost regressor

Tags: python, prediction, xgboost

I'm confused at what seems to be a discrepancy in the score xgboost regressor predicts.

I train a model on a three-sample training set:

```
X = [[1 2],
    [1 2],
    [2 2]]
y = [5, 5, 8]
```

...using this code:

```
reg = XGBRegressor(n_estimators=2,max_depth=2,learning_rate=1.0, silent=False,objective=‘reg:linear’)
reg.fit(X,y)
plot_tree(reg, num_trees=0)
```

...this gives me two trees, per this plot: [plot of two trees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4G4Jt.png)

But I get confused when I predict with a test sample `X_test = [1,2]` because:

```
X_test = [1,2]
reg.predict(X_test)
# print score = 4.875
```

but the score with the trees structure as plotted above should be: `0.25 + 4.125 = 4.375`

Why? Is there anything wrong with my operation?

Comment: well, i find the answer. There is a global bias of 0.5 that gets added to every leaf output. You can remove this bias by setting base_score=0 when training. Thanks for @hcho3 .

Comment: Your question is really unclear. What's confusing: that you can generate a two-tree model from only three samples? how it behaves when you try to predict? something else? Please edit the question for clarity. Also if you answered your own question, please post your self-answer. But only after you first clarify the question. The only thing I get from this is that your question *isn't* about `sklearn api plot_tree()`, because that's only an API that plots your tree, and it's working correctly. But your question is something about the tree itself, not the plotting API.

Comment: Ah, I think you mean your confusion is there's a difference between the value `predict()` gives you, and the value you'd expect when predicting from the two trees as plotted.

Comment: Admittedly, it would be a good enhance if `xgboost plot_tree()` also explicitly showed the `base_score` bias in the plot (if non-zero). But in general I think `base_score` in regressors is bad news. Btw, `plot_tree` has nothing to do with sklearn, it's implemented in `xgboost.plotting` (and based on `graphviz` plotting package, not on `matplotlib`)

Comment: Related: [Why are there discrepancies in xgboost prediction from individual trees?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56621607/why-are-there-discrepancies-in-xgboost-prediction-from-individual-trees)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution: declare your `XGBRegressor` with parameter `base_score=0`**

Per your self-answer in comment, [`xgboost.XGBRegressor(..., base_score)`](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html) applies a bias:

- base_score – The initial prediction score of all instances, global bias.

The (HTML) doc unhelpfully doesn't tell you its default value, but that seems to be `base_score = 0.5`, at least that's what command-line help seems to say. That would be a fine for a (two-class) classifier, but arguably is a terrible default for a regressor, and worse still it isn't documented.

This seems like a legit docbug, please raise it on sklearn.

---

In the unlikely event declaring your `XGBRegressor` with parameter `base_score=0` doesn't solve it, you could try playing with the following (underdocumented) parameters on `fit()` and `predict()` methods (per the command-line doc):

- `fit(... base_margin=None, ...)`
- `predict(..., output_margin=False, base_margin=None)`